# Почему (+ 2 (if (> b a) b a)) возвращает 6?

Tags: lisp, scheme

```
(define a 3)
(define b (+ a 1))
(+ 2 (if (> b a) b a))
REPL: 6

(+ 2 (if (> b a) b a)) == (+ 2 (if (> 4 3) 4 3)) -> (2 + 4 + 3) = 9 ?
```

Не так ведь должно быть ? почему результат 6 а не 9 ?
Я же возвращаю и **b** и **a**...

Comment: `if (> 4 3) 4 3` это `if (4 > 3) 4 else 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы получаете только значение `b`, которое в предыдущей строке установили на 1 больше значения `a`.

Выражение:

```
(if (> b a) b a))
```

возватит `b`, если условие `(> b a)` будет **true**, возвратит значение первого аргумента, т.е. `b`, а если ложно (*nil*), то второго.